# AlexNet get a low accuracy when training

Tags: pytorch, image-classification

I want to use AlexNet to classify my own image dataset, but the accuracy is always around 0.14 during the training process, and the loss is almost unchanged. There are 7 categories in total, and 1 / 7 is exactly 0.1429, so the training does not seem to play a role, and the accuracy rate is random 1 / 7.

my AlexNet code is as follows

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
# from torchsummary import summary

class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nums):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
        
        self.nums = nums
        
        self.conv = nn.Sequential(
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=96, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=96, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=384, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=384, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2)
        )
        
        # self.avg_pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((5, 5))
        
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=6 * 6 * 256, out_features=2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=nums)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        
        # x = self.avg_pool(x)
        
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        # print(x.size())
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x


def alexnet(num_classes):
    return AlexNet(num_classes)
```

My training code is as follows

```
img_transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((227, 227)), transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=train_data_filepath, transform=img_transform)
    val_dataset = torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder(root=val_data_filepath, transform=img_transform)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=Batch_Size, shuffle=True)
    val_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=Batch_Size, shuffle=True)
network = get_network(net_choice).to(device)

loss_function = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=Learning_rate, weight_decay=5e-4)

gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
train_loss, train_accuracy = [], []
val_loss, val_accuracy = [], []
for epoch in range(1, Epoch+1):
    Epoch_start = time.time()
    train_epoch_loss, train_epoch_accuracy = AlexNet_train(
        network, train_dataloader, optimizer, loss_function
        )
    val_epoch_loss, val_epoch_accuracy = AlexNet_Val(
        network, val_dataloader, loss_function
        )
    train_loss.append(train_epoch_loss)
    train_accuracy.append(train_epoch_accuracy)
    val_loss.append(val_epoch_loss)
    val_accuracy.append(val_epoch_accuracy)
```

I tried to change the Learning_rate to 0.001 or 0.01 or 0.0001, and I tried to change the batch_size from 32 to 64 or bigger, it never worked

Comment: What is the size of the original image?

Comment: It's 875*656, the problem is that I used the same way to preprocess the images and it worked in resnet18/resnext50/vgg19/googlenet/SEnet training, but it just couldn't work in AlexNet  @core_not_dumped

Answer (score 0):

It seems that gradient vanishing and exploding occurred because initialization was not performed.
The `He (Kaiming) initialization` method can be used to train the model reliably.

In the code below, the initialization method is applied to the `AlexNet` model.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, nums):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
        
        self.nums = nums
        
        self.conv = [   
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=96, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=0),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=96, out_channels=256, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=384, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=384, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2)
        ]
        
        self.fc = [
            nn.Linear(in_features=6 * 6 * 256, out_features=2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=2048),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=nums)
        ]

        for m in self.conv:
            if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode="fan_out", nonlinearity="relu")
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

        for m in self.fc:
            if isinstance(m, nn.Linear):
                nn.init.kaiming_normal_(m.weight, mode="fan_out", nonlinearity="relu")
                if m.bias is not None:
                    nn.init.constant_(m.bias, 0)

        self.conv = nn.Sequential(*self.conv)
        self.fc = nn.Sequential(*self.fc)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.fc(x)
        return x
```

You can also apply momentum to SGD to make it train better.

And the weight decay seems too large.

```py
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(network.parameters(), lr=Learning_rate, weight_decay=1e-4, momentum=0.9)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it still not worked. The validation accuracy is still 0.1429. Is there any other reason that may cause the problem?  @core_not_dumped

Comment: Try removing the dropout layer. Or try to use smaller model.

Comment: I tried to remove the first dropout layer and use a larger datasets, it worked. But why?